# how to set up cross-directory dependencies in gnu make

Tags: dependencies, g++, makefile, build-automation

I've got a common set of make rules being used in multiple directories.  Each make is very simple:

```
BASEDIR:=../..
TARGET:=theTarget
include Makefile.include
```

Unless overridden, I have a default value for the source code:

```
SRC:= $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

We want to build the object files in a directory (not with the sources), so:

```
OBJDIR:= ../obj
BARE:= $(foreach f,$(SRC),$(notdir $(f) )
OBJ:= $(foreach o,$(BARE),$(OBJDIR)/$(o).o )
```

So I have the .o files, but I need each one to fire a rule based on the .cpp
As long as the directory is known, this is easy:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
```

but in some of the directories, there are arbitrarily grouped files in subdirectories.  I temporarily got around this by hardcoding all of them in my central makefile:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: a/%.cpp
    build...
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: b/%.cpp
    build...
```

But what I'd like to do is be able to specify the build directories in a variable if possible.  Is there any way to set up the dependencies

```
$(OBJDIR)/x.o: a/x.cpp
$(OBJDIR)/y.o: a/y.cpp
```

and

```
$(OBJDIR)/z.o: b/z.cpp
```

without manually having to list out the dependencies?

For that matter, I also have dependency files (.d)

```
$(DEPDIR)/%.d: $(SRC)
```

I want to set up dependencies based on whatever is in the source.
For example:
    .deps/x.d: a/x.cpp
        g++ -MM -MT$(objdir)/$(notdir $@) $< -o $(DEPDIR)/$(notdir $@ )

Is there an easy way to generate these rules without writing them for each directory?

Here's where I got the information on generating the .d files in the first place:
http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html#advanced

The goal in the end is to include all the .d files and have dependence tree auto-generated from the files.  But that is the last part.  I don't know how to use the .d files.  Do I just include them all?

```
include $(DEPDIR)/%.d
```

doesn't work.

I can cat them all together in a rule:
     cat $(DEP) >$(DEPDIR)/deps.inc

and then

```
include deps.inc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to cope with the source directories:

```
vpath %.cpp a b

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    build...
```

Then if you want you can generate the dependency files like this:

```
# Might as well use DEPDIR, rather than "deps"

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: %.cpp 
    g++ -MM ...

# Note the wildcard. And the '-' at the beginning means
# "don't panic if there aren't any".

-include $(DEPDIR)/*.d
```

But there is a better way which is described in the source you cite. Don't make a rule for the `.d` files, just build them in the same rule that builds the object files. That way you don't build them unless you actually need them.

Comment: Thanks for the include $(DEPDIR)/*.d